# how to strip punctuation in php

Tags: php, string, strip

How can I strip punctuation except for these characters `.` `=` `$` `'` `-` `€` `%`

Comment: What do you mean? Please add more detail and examples.

Comment: It would probably be easier to just keep the characters you want. Do you just want to retain a-z (upper and lower) 0-9 and the characters you've listed? Also, what's "phpr"?

Comment: @middaparka It's a new collaboration between PHP and [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) :)

Comment: @alex Cool. I'm personally holding out for PHCOBOL. :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since you need to match some Unicode characters (`€`) it would be sensible to use a regular expression. The pattern `\p{P}` matches any known punctuation, and the assertion excludes your desired special characters from vanishing:

```
 $text = preg_replace("/(?![.=$'€%-])\p{P}/u", "", $text);
```

Comment: Can you please explain this pattern, I am a newbie in PCRE, and it's the first time I see a `(?!)` which is not a lookahead, or something I just don't understand. Also, I don't understand `\p{P}`

Comment: @AlexanderMP: The negative lookahead `(?!...)` assertion is best explained here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html -- And the `\p{P}` is somewhat cryptic, but there is also a nice overview there: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: This does not remove `'` characters.

Comment: @mopsyd Yep, and it's not supposed to. ("Except for these chracters...")

Answer (score 46):

Here's a neat way to do it:

```
preg_replace("#[[:punct:]]#", "", $target);
```

Comment: I like this quite a bit.

Comment: This cannot be the correct answer as it strips all punctuation but the original question specifies exceptions.

Comment: this is the correct answer Even if they are non-Latin characters like arabic characters

Answer (score 8):

```
<?
$whatToStrip = array("?","!",",",";"); // Add what you want to strip in this array
$test = "Hi! Am I here?";
echo $test."\n\n";
echo str_replace($whatToStrip, "", $test);
```

[Demo here](http://codepad.org/9hyK0KSX)

or, of course, shorter :

```
$test = str_replace(array("?","!",",",";"), "", $test);
```

---

[Source from 1st example of `str_replace` manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("[^-\w\d\s\.=$'€%]",'',$subject)
```

although it would be more correct and easy to specify the characters you want to strip, instead of characters (from an unknown set) you don't want to strip.

Comment: You don't have to escape `$` inside of a character class - but AFAIK `-` should be the first or last item.

Comment: Could be. I just feel more comfortable when escaping all special chars which are used in PCRE. But thanks for the hint.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
preg_replace("/[^\w-\p{L}\p{N}\p{Pd}\$\.€%']/", "", 'YOUR DATA');
```

You didn't mentioned if you wanted spaces or not, so that will strip that too.

Answer (score -2):

The problem:

Need to save string as alphaNum with specific punctuation and don't want to completely discard characters with special punctuation.

The solution:

```
class ClassName {

  protected static $cleanChars = array(
    '&lt;' => '', '&gt;' => '', '&#039;' => '', '&amp;' => '',
    '&quot;' => '', 'À' => 'A', 'Á' => 'A', 'Â' => 'A', 'Ã' => 'A', 'Ä' => 'Ae',
    '&Auml;' => 'A', 'Å' => 'A', 'Ā' => 'A', 'Ą' => 'A', 'Ă' => 'A', 'Æ' => 'Ae',
    'Ç' => 'C', 'Ć' => 'C', 'Č' => 'C', 'Ĉ' => 'C', 'Ċ' => 'C', 'Ď' => 'D', 'Đ' => 'D',
    'Ð' => 'D', 'È' => 'E', 'É' => 'E', 'Ê' => 'E', 'Ë' => 'E', 'Ē' => 'E',
    'Ę' => 'E', 'Ě' => 'E', 'Ĕ' => 'E', 'Ė' => 'E', 'Ĝ' => 'G', 'Ğ' => 'G',
    'Ġ' => 'G', 'Ģ' => 'G', 'Ĥ' => 'H', 'Ħ' => 'H', 'Ì' => 'I', 'Í' => 'I',
    'Î' => 'I', 'Ï' => 'I', 'Ī' => 'I', 'Ĩ' => 'I', 'Ĭ' => 'I', 'Į' => 'I',
    'İ' => 'I', 'Ĳ' => 'IJ', 'Ĵ' => 'J', 'Ķ' => 'K','Ł' => 'K', 'Ľ' => 'K',
    'Ĺ' => 'K', 'Ļ' => 'K', 'Ŀ' => 'K', 'Ñ' => 'N', 'Ń' => 'N', 'Ň' => 'N',
    'Ņ' => 'N', 'Ŋ' => 'N', 'Ò' => 'O', 'Ó' => 'O', 'Ô' => 'O', 'Õ' => 'O',
    'Ö' => 'Oe', '&Ouml;' => 'Oe', 'Ø' => 'O', 'Ō' => 'O', 'Ő' => 'O', 'Ŏ' => 'O',
    'Œ' => 'OE', 'Ŕ' => 'R', 'Ř' => 'R', 'Ŗ' => 'R', 'Ś' => 'S', 'Š' => 'S',
    'Ş' => 'S', 'Ŝ' => 'S', 'Ș' => 'S', 'Ť' => 'T', 'Ţ' => 'T', 'Ŧ' => 'T',
    'Ț' => 'T', 'Ù' => 'U', 'Ú' => 'U', 'Û' => 'U', 'Ü' => 'Ue', 'Ū' => 'U',
    '&Uuml;' => 'Ue', 'Ů' => 'U', 'Ű' => 'U', 'Ŭ' => 'U', 'Ũ' => 'U', 'Ų' => 'U',
    'Ŵ' => 'W', 'Ý' => 'Y', 'Ŷ' => 'Y', 'Ÿ' => 'Y', 'Ź' => 'Z', 'Ž' => 'Z',
    'Ż' => 'Z', 'Þ' => 'T', 'à' => 'a', 'á' => 'a', 'â' => 'a', 'ã' => 'a',
    'ä' => 'ae', '&auml;' => 'ae', 'å' => 'a', 'ā' => 'a', 'ą' => 'a', 'ă' => 'a',
    'æ' => 'ae', 'ç' => 'c', 'ć' => 'c', 'č' => 'c', 'ĉ' => 'c', 'ċ' => 'c',
    'ď' => 'd', 'đ' => 'd', 'ð' => 'd', 'è' => 'e', 'é' => 'e', 'ê' => 'e',
    'ë' => 'e', 'ē' => 'e', 'ę' => 'e', 'ě' => 'e', 'ĕ' => 'e', 'ė' => 'e',
    'ƒ' => 'f', 'ĝ' => 'g', 'ğ' => 'g', 'ġ' => 'g', 'ģ' => 'g', 'ĥ' => 'h',
    'ħ' => 'h', 'ì' => 'i', 'í' => 'i', 'î' => 'i', 'ï' => 'i', 'ī' => 'i',
    'ĩ' => 'i', 'ĭ' => 'i', 'į' => 'i', 'ı' => 'i', 'ĳ' => 'ij', 'ĵ' => 'j',
    'ķ' => 'k', 'ĸ' => 'k', 'ł' => 'l', 'ľ' => 'l', 'ĺ' => 'l', 'ļ' => 'l',
    'ŀ' => 'l', 'ñ' => 'n', 'ń' => 'n', 'ň' => 'n', 'ņ' => 'n', 'ŉ' => 'n',
    'ŋ' => 'n', 'ò' => 'o', 'ó' => 'o', 'ô' => 'o', 'õ' => 'o', 'ö' => 'oe',
    '&ouml;' => 'oe', 'ø' => 'o', 'ō' => 'o', 'ő' => 'o', 'ŏ' => 'o', 'œ' => 'oe',
    'ŕ' => 'r', 'ř' => 'r', 'ŗ' => 'r', 'š' => 's', 'ù' => 'u', 'ú' => 'u',
    'û' => 'u', 'ü' => 'ue', 'ū' => 'u', '&uuml;' => 'ue', 'ů' => 'u', 'ű' => 'u',
    'ŭ' => 'u', 'ũ' => 'u', 'ų' => 'u', 'ŵ' => 'w', 'ý' => 'y', 'ÿ' => 'y',
    'ŷ' => 'y', 'ž' => 'z', 'ż' => 'z', 'ź' => 'z', 'þ' => 't', 'ß' => 'ss',
    'ſ' => 'ss', 'ый' => 'iy', 'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V', 'Г' => 'G',
    'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E', 'Ё' => 'YO', 'Ж' => 'ZH', 'З' => 'Z', 'И' => 'I',
    'Й' => 'Y', 'К' => 'K', 'Л' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N', 'О' => 'O',
    'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R', 'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T', 'У' => 'U', 'Ф' => 'F',
    'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'C', 'Ч' => 'CH', 'Ш' => 'SH', 'Щ' => 'SCH', 'Ъ' => '',
    'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ь' => '', 'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'YU', 'Я' => 'YA', 'а' => 'a',
    'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'yo',
    'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'y', 'к' => 'k', 'л' => 'l',
    'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's',
    'т' => 't', 'у' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c', 'ч' => 'ch',
    'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sch', 'ъ' => '', 'ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'э' => 'e',
    'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya'
  );

  public static function clean($string, $allowed=array(), $base="a-zA-Z0-9 "){
    if(empty($allowed) && !$base){ return false; }
    $ignore = "";
    if(is_array($allowed)){
      foreach($allowed as $a){
        $ignore .= preg_quote($a);
      }
    }
    return preg_replace( "/[^{$base}{$ignore}\s]/", "", $string );
  }

  public static function alphaNum($string, $allowed=array(), $convert=false){
    if($convert){
      $string = strtr($string, self::$cleanChars);
    }
    return self::clean($string, $allowed, 'a-zA-Z0-9 ');
  }

}
```

Examples:

Strip all punctuation:

ClassName::alpaNum($string);

Strip all punctuation but convert special chars:

ClassName::alphaNum($string, null, true);

Alpha Num + additional punctuation:

ClassName::alphaNum($string, array('_', '-', ',', '.'));

Alpha Num + additional punctuation and convert:

ClassName::alphaNum($string, array('_', '-', ',', '.'), true);

Conclusion:
If you are expecting special chars and don't completely want to discard them you can convert them before checking alphaNum.
(eg. on sanitizing file names etc.)

If discarding the special chars does not have any real impact and is not really expected on the system you can call it without conversion of punctuation to save processing power.
(eg. on setting keys for large arrays from strings)

I got the cleanChars var from here:
(I slightly modified it)
https://github.com/vanillaforums/Garden/blob/master/library/core/class.format.php

Comment: This is totally crazy